# __proto__ deprecated. What is fast and cross browser alternative?

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype-programming

As you know, `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

> MDN:
>   Warning: The `__proto__` property is deprecated and should not be used.

what is fast and cross browser alternative for `__proto__`?
In my case I change `__proto__` of a function. So I can't find any alternative.

deprecated code

```
// one time
var proto = {};
proto.bar = function (x) { return this(x) + 10; };
proto.buzz = function () { return this(4); };
// and 100 more function proto.*
proto = _.extend(proto, (function(){}).__proto__); // underscore extend function
                                                   // update: change arguments order

// many time
var foo = function (x) { return 2 * x; }
foo.__proto__ = proto;
```

slow alternative ([jsperf](http://jsperf.com/proto-vs-set))

```
// many time
var foo = function (x) { return 2 * x; };
foo.bar = function (x) { return this(x) + 10; };
foo.buzz = function () { return this(4); };
// and 100 more function foo.*
```

Is there any fast and cross browser alternative?

Comment: In your jsPerf, the tests are heavily slanted toward the `__proto__` version because you're reusing the functions in that one and not in the second one.

Comment: ...another reason for your jsPerf results, is that you're actually modifying `Function.prototype` by adding the methods directly to it, so your `foo.__proto__ = proto;` is actually doing `foo.__proto__ = Function.prototype`, which doesn't change anything. It's a NO-OP.

Comment: Txn. I change order of extend argumens.

Comment: So what happens if you redo the test with that change and also so that the "slow" version reuses the existing functions? `foo.bar = proto.bar; foo.buzz = proto.buzz; // etc...`

Comment: `foo.__proto__` has best performance and `foo.bar = proto.bar` is better than `foo.bar = function(){...}`

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the linked MDN article, [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is the new function. It seems to have pretty good browser support. For those that don't support it (except IE), you can shim it with `__proto__`. ;)

```
if (!Object.getProtoTypeOf) {
    Object.getProtoTypeOf = function(obj) {
        return obj.__proto__;
    };
}
```

Comment: And what about `foo.__proto__ = proto;`?

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf()`

Comment: Safari: Not supported, Internet Explorer: 11, Firefox: 31, Chrome 34

Answer (score 2):

In your first use, you're getting the `__proto__` of a function, so you can simply use `Function.prototype`

```
proto = _.extend(Function.prototype, proto); // underscore extend function
```

Your second use is replacing the prototype on an object, so there's no alternative.

ECMAScript 6 is standardizing `__proto__`, and will also have `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, so you'll be able to use them once implemented.

Comment: Why not simply `Object.create`?

Comment: *"ECMAScript 6 is standardizing `__proto__`"* Source? It's not in the spec.

Comment: @FelixKling: The current draft has it.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: @FelixKling Is this it, in B.2.2.1? https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__

Comment: @FelixKling: Sure, but it's an open standard ;-) http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks! ctrl+f `__proto__` only pointed me to `http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers` . I guess the document is too large to be searched :-/ Or my browser just messed up, because now it works...

Comment: Notice that ES6 is standardizing the *deprecation of* `__proto__` :-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's important to point this out: *"When the ECMAScript host is a web browser the following additional properties of the standard built-in objects are defined."* . So `__proto__` should not be used with Node.js (if it's even supported, no idea).

Comment: @FelixKling: I would think Google's V8 project would make a decision as to whether or not they're going to support it. Once they do, it should be as safe to use as any other feature. Since it's the same engine used in browsers, seems likely that it'll be there.